# Slideshow / Carousel Javascript not working in an external file

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, slideshow

I am new to programming in general, so I apologize if my question is not constructive and clear but I took my time and hope to visualize the issue. I tested out Javascript and want an imageslider with basic javascript.
However I cannot figure out why my code will not funcntion when the javascript is written in an external sheet.

The imageslider will not initially show up when the page load, but it is working when written inside HTML file.

Here is the code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) example

> here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rinseo/h7osk96e/)

> The javascript:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

Everything seems to be working perfectly fine untill I put this into separate script file.

```
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>
```

Function is working [here](https://gph.is/g/Eve9zwV) with javascript inside html

Function is ***NOT*** working [here](https://gph.is/g/Eq57mjD) with javascript written in external file.

> > > `
> > > this is what debug info says

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
at showSlides (slider.js:27)
at slider.js:3`

showSlides(slideIndex);    This shows error   
slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";   This shows error
```

Comment: see your debug info,I bet on a relative path error

Comment: What debug info?
If you mean relative path, I have tried "../js/slider.js" it will not at all.

Comment: maybe you are trying to access data from a place that CAN'T see the js file!

Comment: a simple and dirty way is to add an alert or log in your code in that file... that way you KNOW if the code is being run at all... plus, add a type: type="application/javascript"

Answer (score 0):

Please check where you have placed you `<script>` tag if it is placed in `<head>` ,then place it just above the `</body>` this will solve your problem.

Please reffer this code:

*script.js*

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
    dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
}
```

*index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Sample</title>
      <style> 
         * {
            box-sizing: border-box
         }
         body {
            font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
            margin: 0
         }
         .mySlides {
            display: none
         }
         img {
            vertical-align: middle;
         }
         /* Slideshow container */
         .slideshow-container {
            max-width: 1000px;
            position: relative;
            margin: auto;
         }
         /* Next & previous buttons */
         .prev,
         .next {
            cursor: pointer;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            width: auto;
            padding: 16px;
            margin-top: -22px;
            color: white;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 18px;
            transition: 0.6s ease;
            border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
            user-select: none;
         }
         /* Position the "next button" to the right */
         .next {
            right: 0;
            border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
         }
         /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
         .prev:hover,
         .next:hover {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
         }
         /* Caption text */
         .text {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            font-size: 15px;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 8px;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
         }
         /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
         .numbertext {
            color: #f2f2f2;
            font-size: 12px;
            padding: 8px 12px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
         }
         /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
         .dot {
            cursor: pointer;
            height: 15px;
            width: 15px;
            margin: 0 2px;
            background-color: #bbb;
            border-radius: 50%;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
         }
         .active,
         .dot:hover {
            background-color: #717171;
         }
         /* Fading animation */
         .fade {
            -webkit-animation-name: fade;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
            animation-name: fade;
            animation-duration: 1.5s;
         }
         @-webkit-keyframes fade {
           from {
             opacity: .4
           }
           to {
             opacity: 1
           }
         }
         @keyframes fade {
           from {
             opacity: .4
           }
           to {
             opacity: 1
           }
         }
         /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
         @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
         .prev,
         .next,
         .text {
            font-size: 11px
           }
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="slideshow-container">
         <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
            <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
         </div>
         <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
            <img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
         </div>
         <div class="mySlides fade">
            <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
            <img src="img_mountains_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
            <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
         </div>
         <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
         <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div style="text-align:center">
         <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
         <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
         <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
      </div>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

for more clarification please download this code : [Sample Slider.zip](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/quizbox-f1bb1.appspot.com/o/Sample.zip?alt=media&token=5bdedb74-6df5-4ab0-9adb-0c231190b452)

Comment: What if I want an external javascript file? 
The code is working when written inline HTML as I mentioned above.

Comment: This is really weird, the codes you provided works when I copy it over. What's more frustrating now is that I have no clue where I did a mistake. The debug info is not showing anything now, any clue where I did wrong above?

Comment: check the script tag. i have added it at the end just before the closing tag of body

Comment: please check the sample source code (the zip file)  i added. you might have added the script tag in the head section. the problem is that since you have added the script tag before at the head. the js executes before the element is added to the DOM. so when you are trying to set the style to an element that doenot exist so it shows undefined error.

Comment: if your problem is solved can you plz mark the question as solved.

Comment: if you still have any doubt on this issue.please add the complete code. i can help you.

Comment: i think you have solved your problem, please mark the question as solved.